# how can i write only the pos tag without words?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform POS tagging to my text which are present in the dataframe. I tried using TextBlob, but I am not getting the desired result. My desired result is "a new column should be created with all the taggings". Eg:"I like stackoverflow" and my new column POS_tagged should have [('I', 'PRP'), ('like', 'VBP'), ('stackoverflow', 'JJ')]

```
[(What, WP), (is, VBZ), (the, DT),...]
[(Which, WDT), (is, VBZ), (the, DT),...]
```

and i want to be like that

```
[ WP,VBZ,DT,...]
[ WDT, VBZ, DT,...]
```

Comment: that is dataframe

Comment: then please provide a dataframe constructor, your current format is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. Yet, if you have a dataframe of tuples and want to subset the tuples, use `applymap`:

input

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[(0,1), (2,3)], [(4,5), (6,7)]])
>>> df
        0       1
0  (0, 1)  (2, 3)
1  (4, 5)  (6, 7)
```

```
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: x[1])
   0  1
0  1  3
1  5  7
```

Comment: i got

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: Then it's not a DataFrame, please provide the output of `your_series.to_dict()`

Comment: in my data frame i have 3 column and the third column is the postags eith word sequence

Comment: [(What, WP), (is, VBZ), (the, DT),...] this is my third column

Comment: @xsrg45 this is not what I requested ;) whatever is your object, add `.to_dict()` at the end and edit your question to provide the dictionary returned by this command

Comment: good thanks i have one more question i want to add from simpletransformers.classification import MultiLabelClassificationModel but i gir rhis error ValueError: pyarrow.lib.Codec size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
add Codeadd Markdown

Comment: This is a different problem, please open an new question. Is the problem in this question solved?

Comment: i open it here no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031748/how-can-i-import-multilabelclassificationmodel-from-simpletransformers-classific

Comment: Let's focus on the current question. It is solved?